# Using csv to graph in Python

Tags: python, csv, graph

This is what I currently have and now I am stuck. The program is supposed to take a specific column from a csv file then it needs to be input into the first turbidity equation above, which will then give the turbidity. From there I need the turbidity to be graphed along with the time on the x axis. How would I go about doing this? To clarify the input from the csv file is volts, it needs to be converted to turbidity then graphed on the y axis.

These are the times: `6/27/2018 12:30, 6/27/2018 12:45, 6/27/2018 13:00`
These are the volts: `1530102610, 1530103515,1530104412`

`Turbidity = (0.07642 * volts) + (-15.122))` this is the equation.

```
 Date/Time (UTC)    Logger Time (unix timestamp)    Raw Sensor (mV) LoggerID
    6/27/2018 18:45 1530125111  4.61    Mill Creek B
    7/3/2018 18:30  1530642609  92.14   Mill Creek B
    7/3/2018 18:45  1530643509  92.03   Mill Creek B
    7/3/2018 20:00  1530648013  91.24   Mill Creek B
```

...

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
headers = ['Raw Sensor','Date','Time']
df = pd.read_csv('turbiditydata.csv',names=headers)
print (df)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))
x = df['Date']
y = df['Turbidity']


plt.plot(x,y)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.title('Turbidity Over Time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please paste the actual input of the file, in its actual format. Also you need to fix your indentation, your current code won't run because of it. Also a link to the Turbidity equation would help since you're current;y just overwriting the values and not storing them anywhere. Plus you never define `x` and `y`!

Comment: Is the csv data available?

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop? It has no connection to any of the rest of the code... please remove it if it's not needed for the question

Comment: Yes I posted the csv data above, the times and the volts

Comment: @user6824158 post it *exactly* as it appears in the csv file. Also you just made the indentation worse! Still no formula for turbidity. And what is `date_and_time` suddenly??? Please read [hot to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We should be able to copy and paste your code and it should run (at least so the same point you get errors)

Comment: I have given you the formula Turbidity = (0.07642 * volts) + (-15.122)). The data is in an excel file.

Comment: @Dan I updated it could you please help

Comment: Seems fine at first glance, except you haven't defined `df['Turbidity']` yet.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: so... `y = 0.07642*df['Raw Sensor'] - 15.122`?